# How to detect response in VueJS?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, vuejs2, xmlhttprequest, vuex

I ask the help of knowledgeable people
im create a RESTfull API project on Vue.js (Vuex also)
And im get small problem
The server to which I am sending the request is down why how idn
Can someone tell me how can im detect this message from response
[image]

[image]

This response dont have any massege, error, status, statusText, text, preview and response
All this field is empty
If someone have expirience about this or some info I will be very grateful for that

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to handle these cases:

```js
submitRequest() {
  axios.post('/api/test', this.testData)
    .then(response => {
      // handle success
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      if (error.response) {
        // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      } else if (error.request) {
        // YOU CAN HANDLE IT HERE
        // The request was made but no response was received
        // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser
        console.log(error.request);
      } else {
        // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      }
    });
}
```